# How React context API works in case of nested components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend, react-context

I have some Question in mind while switching to context API in react js .

> 1. What is the advantages of New context API in React js .
> 2. Can we use Redux along with context api ?
> 3. What are the overcome of context api on redux if any ?

Answer (score 1):

so here is the answers to your questions.

1. With context react now have builtin support for state management so you don't need third party lib like redux or mobx.
2. Yes, you can but not required, however, you can use reducers with context to handle complex state management.
3. Less boilerplate code, especially with hooks and not dependency on third party lib and for small project context, makes it very simple and easy.

If you are looking for example then I created this repo to demo and check other branches to explore more ways of using context.

https://github.com/smkamranqadri/react-hooks-context-todo